# Grids anidados con react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, reactjs, typescript

Estoy renderizando una view para mostrar productos, estoy tratando de acomodar unas cards dentro de un row pero no consigo el resultado deseado.Creo estar equivocado en la forma que los aprendi a usar , y por eso estoy teniendo este problema. 
Asi es como deberia de lucir:
[image: Esta es la pantalla que estoy tratando de renderizar]

Actualmente la llevo asi:

[image: He probado a cambiar los tamaños de los componentes pero aun no consigo lograrlo]

Este es el codigo de mi componente Card, que son cada una de las tarjetas que se crean por cada producto:

```
<Card>
        <Row>
            <Col md="5">
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={proveedorImg} />
            </Col>
            <Col md="7">
            <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
                <small><p className="card-text"><strong>Codigo: </strong>{id}</p></small>
                <small><p className="card-text"><strong>Precio:</strong> L. {precio}.00</p></small>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Card>
```

y esta mi vista donde las estoy queriendo poner :

```
<NavBarO/>
           <Container>
               <Row>
                   <Col md="4">
                   <TabVertical/> 
                   </Col>
                   <Col>
                       <Row>
                          <Col sm="4">
                            {productos.map((sup: IProductos, index)=>(
                                <Card3
                                 name = {sup.NameProducto}
                                 id = {sup.IDProducto}
                                 precio = {sup.ValorVenta}
                                />
                            ))}  
                          </Col>    
                      </Row> 
                   </Col>
               </Row>
           </Container>
```